# How can a system of complex specific equations be solved in the form of a matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have been trying for a very long time to solve a system of difficult specific equations, where there are 6 (six) unknown variables X (x1 ....). Using Python and various compute modules. It is not difficult to do it manually - find X (x1 ....). I'm trying to come up with a matrix plot for this. I would be very glad for any help.

x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6

```
-x1 +x2 = 0
-x2 +x3 +x4 +30 = 0
-x3 + x5 = 0
-x5 +25 = 0
-x4 +x6 = 0
-x6 +15 +55 = 0 

-1 +1 0 0
-1 +1 +1 +30
-1 +1 0 0
-1 +25 0 0
-1 +1 0 0 
-1 +15 +55 0
```

code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import openpyxl
import math
import scipy.sparse
import scipy.sparse.linalg
from scipy.linalg import solve

A = np.array( [ [-1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [-1, 1, 1, 30, 0, 0], \
                [-1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [-1, 25, 0, 0, 0, 0], \
                [-1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [-1, 15, 55, 0, 0, 0] ])


Vh = np.linalg.svd(A)

y = np.array( [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] )

# A_inv = np.linalg.lstsq(A)
x = np.matmul(Vh, y)
# x = np.linalg.solve(Vh, y)
print(x)

C:\Dash_board\uchpotkot.py:110: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  x = np.matmul(Vh, y)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Dash_board\uchpotkot.py", line 110, in <module>
    x = np.matmul(Vh, y)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (6,6) into shape (6,)
```

Comment: Your coefficient matrix and `y` matrix are incorrect. See [here](https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/representing-systems-of-linear-equations-using-matrices)

Comment: How i can add\insert values from dataframe to elements matrix?

Comment: Reread the `np.linalg.svd` docs.  What does it return?  You assume `Vh` is a simple array.  But it returns a tuple of arrays.  `matmul` tries to make a single array from that tuple, resulting in the `RAGGED ARRAY` warning and error.  Learning to read the docs can save you a lot of time and unnecessary SO postings!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're using `np.linalg.svd` correctly. Per [the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html), it returns 3 separate arrays, `u`, `s`, and `vh`.

Instead of

```
Vh = np.linalg.svd(A)
```

write

```
u, s, vh = np.linalg.svd(A)
```

Comment: What's wrong with this answer?

Answer (score 0):

richardec is right for the SVD part, but also it might be more simple than what you're doing here. You're just looking for all value of the x variables, right?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse.linalg
from scipy.linalg import solve

A = np.array( [[-1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
               [0, -1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0],
               [0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0],
               [0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1],
               [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1]])

b = np.array([0, -30, 0, -25, 0, -70])

x = np.linalg.solve(A, b)

print(x)
[125., 125.,  25.,  70.,  25.,  70.]
```

The A matrix is the variable coefficients and b is the value of each expression.

Comment: How i can add\insert values from dataframe to elements matrix?

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of red herrings in your code, it's important to focus on just what is needed.

You are trying to solve n equations with n unknowns using a linear algebra matrix solution.  The overall approach here is that you set up your equations into a matrix form of:

```
A * x = b
```

where A is a matrix of the coefficients of your unknowns, x is a vector of unknowns, and b is a vector of constants.
Once you have those defined, you can solve for x by multiplying both sides by the inverse of A:

```
x = inverse(A) * b
```

Your code above does not define the coefficient (A) matrix correctly, nor is the constant matrix (b) correct.
Your A matrix should be:

```
[-1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0]
[ 0, -1,  1,  1,  0,  0]
[ 0,  0, -1,  0,  1,  0]
[ 0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0]
[ 0,  0,  0, -1,  0,  1]
[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1]
```

and your constant (b) vector should be:

```
[  0]
[-30]
[  0]
[-25]
[  0]
[-70]
```

Once you've defined both of those, the answer is pretty easy to get using the equation above:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array( [ [-1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0], 
                [ 0, -1,  1,  1,  0,  0], 
                [ 0,  0, -1,  0,  1,  0], 
                [ 0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0],
                [ 0,  0,  0, -1,  0,  1],
                [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1] ])

b = np.transpose(np.array([0,-30,0,-25,0,-15-55]))
unknowns = np.transpose(np.array(['x1','x2','x3','x4','x5','x6']))

result = np.matmul(np.linalg.inv(A),b)

for i in range(len(result)):
    print('{} = {}'.format(unknowns[i],result[i]))
```

result:

```
x1 = 125.0
x2 = 125.0
x3 = 25.0
x4 = 70.0
x5 = 25.0
x6 = 70.0
```

Comment: ( [ [-1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0], 
[ 0, -1,  1,  1,  0,  0], 
[ 0,  0, -1,  0,  1,  0], 
[ 0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0],
[ 0,  0,  0, -1,  0,  1],
[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1] ])Thanks a lot! How can I make such a matrix as your first one based on my equations?

Comment: Not sure I follow?  The A matrix I have in my sample code **is** the matrix from your equations!

Comment: To be clearer, in each of your equations you **must** include a 0 for each variable that doesn't appear.  So you will get a 6 x 6 array of coefficients (6 equations, 6 coefficients for each unknown).  This is exactly the A matrix I defined above for your equations.